# Can I determine, though typetraits, whether a type has the const modifier?

Tags: c++, type-traits

Just as the question says, can I find out whether a type has a `const` modifier via `typetraits`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11, you can use [`std::is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const). Just include `<type_traits>` header.

In C++03, it is easy to implement this yourself:

```
template<typename T> 
struct is_const 
{
    const static bool value = false;
};

template<typename T> 
struct is_const<const T>
{
    const static bool value = true;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::is_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const), if you have c++11 support. Otherwise, use [boost::is_const](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_const.html).

```
struct Foo {};

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
....
std::cout << std::is_const<Foo>::value << '\n';  // false
std::cout << std::is_const<const Foo>::value  << '\n'; // true
```